# Eval() showing null value

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using the `<%#Eval("sectionId") %>` data binding expression to bind the data to my code-in-front.
I am setting this sectionId in my code behinde using the following code,

```
public partial class ProductDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string sectionId = string.Empty;           

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Request.QueryString["secId"] != null || Request.QueryString["prodId"] != null)
                    {
                        sectionId = Request.QueryString["secId"].ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where in my .aspx page i have code like this,

```
<a href="SectionWiseProduct.aspx?secId=<%#Eval("sectionId") %>">Enviro Section</a>
```

every time value for sectionId is set successfully in code behinde but the it is not reflected in the UI page.every time i am getting the link like,

```
SectionWiseProduct.aspx?secId=
```

can anybody please suggest is i am doing right or is there any other way to do that.
And also the page_Load calls twice,is this because of the Eval ?

Answer (score 0):

Make that change in your code that will work

```
public string sectionId = string.Empty;
```

hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Minimize Calls to DataBinder.Eval**

The DataBinder.Eval method uses reflection to evaluate the arguments that are passed in and to return the results. If you have a table that has 100 rows and 10 columns, you call DataBinder.Eval 1,000 times if you use DataBinder.Eval on each column. Your choice to use DataBinder.Eval is multiplied 1,000 times in this scenario. Limiting the use of DataBinder.Eval during data binding operations significantly improves page performance. Consider the following ItemTemplate element within a Repeater control using DataBinder.Eval.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"field1") %></td>
    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"field2") %></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

There are alternatives to using DataBinder.Eval in this scenario. The alternatives include the following:

Use explicit casting. Using explicit casting offers better performance by avoiding the cost of reflection. Cast the Container.DataItem as a DataRowView.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["field1"] %></td>
    <td><%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["field2"] %></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can gain even better performance with explicit casting if you use a DataReader to bind your control and use the specialized methods to retrieve your data. Cast the Container.DataItem as a DbDataRecord.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
     <td><%# ((DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem).GetString(0) %></td>
     <td><%# ((DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem).GetInt(1) %></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The explicit casting depends on the type of data source you are binding to; the preceding code illustrates an example.

Use the ItemDataBound event. If the record that is being data bound contains many fields, it may be more efficient to use the ItemDataBound event. By using this event, you only perform the type conversion once. The following sample uses a DataSet object.

```
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
  Response.Write(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>",drv["field1"]));
  Response.Write(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>",drv["field2"]));
  Response.Write(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>",drv["field3"]));
  Response.Write(string.Format("<td>{0}</td>",drv["field4"]));
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for reply can you suggest me any solution using which i can bind the data to plain HTML control.Beacuse i want to bind data to the `<a>` tag.

Comment: yes sure, make the <a> tag run at server and bind it in the ItemDataBound event, very easy to do and more readable later.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution

just use

```
<%=sectionId %>
```

insted of

```
<%#Eval("sectionId") %>
```

but every time on page load the value get refreshed,you just need to handle it other wise its working fine with me :)

hop its help to other.